# How to find source of dlls and js files?

Tags: javascript, powershell, dll, open-source, conventions

I'm building a Powershell script to find the source of dlls and js files. This is to keep track of internal and external code.

So far for dlls, I've come up with `$dll.VersionInfo.LegalCopyright` which works if they provide copyright information. (e.g. Microsoft, Twitter, Google, Company, etc)

If there's a better way, do tell.

However, I'm stumped on JS files. For most cases, the js file will be just jQuery but not always.

JS files aren't compiled so there isn't anything I can scrape from. Maybe inside the file? Is there a pattern/convention that developers sign js files with that I can try to match?

Comment: Your awareness of the opt-in behavior (_".. works if they provide copyright information"_) would apply equally to a `.js` file as well.  Is there an existing example within your company/industry that you can point to, that has a basic "signing" of any kind?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it further, this seems like a far-fetched endeavor. There is no way to generalize all the signing conventions of everyone.  For the time being, I'll just separate js into Jquery and Other, seeing as how 90% of the js files seem to be Jquery.

Comment: @gravity made a good point, did you read it? If you can get your company to sign(1) all *your companies* files, you can search on that and mark all others as external. *(1) signing could be anything as the legalcopyright in a dll, a header in a .js file, ...*

Comment: Yes, I did. I simply don't have that power so going further with this would be fruitless.